# Difference between reverse and reverse_lazy?

Tags: python, django

I read more projects in Django however I didn't understand!

```py
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

like this

Comment: `reverse` is immediately resolved. But at that moment the `path`s are not constructed yet. So if it is defined at class level it will fail. if you do this in a method (that is thus postponed until the view is triggered, then the paths are loaded). `reverse_lazy` is thus a way to *postpone* URL resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`reverse(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) is a function that, for a given view name and parameters, can construct the path. But there is a problem with *resolve*: it can only work if the `urls.py` is loaded.

Typically the `views.py` file is imported by the `urls.py`, so that means that the `views.py` is loaded *before* the `urls.py`. This thus means that if you call `reverse(…)` at the class level or in a decorator like `@login_required(login_url=reverse('view-name'))`, it is immediately processed when you the file is loaded. At that point the paths are not yet defined, so that will error.

A solution to this is to postpone evaluation. [**`reverse_lazy(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) does this. Instead of immediately evaluating it, it simply stores the name of the view, the parameters, etc. and promises to later call `reverse` when necessary.

If you have a view where the `reverse` is called in a *function* for example, then this is usually not a problem, unless the function is called when you load the module of course. So one can for example define a function:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('login')
```

This works because here `.get_success_url(…)` is only called when the view is invoked and was successful. This is long after the paths are loaded.